# Server side - Progress Bar

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2

I am currently working on a file conversion program, once the file has been uploaded it will convert the file to different file formats(ppt,pdf) this will usually take long depending on the file size. Since the file conversion is happening on the back end, I want the user to see the progress of the file conversion( something like progress bar eg "52% file being converted") is there anyway I can display to the user the current progress of the file conversion(that's happening on the back end)?  During file conversion I am only able to show the status(in numbers(provided by the API I am using))

I have no idea where to start can someone provide some insight or approach?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-file-upload-progress-bar/ **in pure simple JS** ok, it's for upload but XHR requests are your point of interest. Otherwise you can show the upload bar, and than after upload is over just animate a loading bar like 'Converting your file... please wait'

Comment: There's a good tutorial at http://tpeczek.blogspot.in/2010/07/reporting-server-side-operation.html

Comment: @roXon I am not talking about file upload progress bar, what i mean is that there's a certain process running on the backend(file conversion)  I want to show it's progress to the user

Comment: @Mukund_Roy I am usng JSP/Java  though.

Comment: You will need to adopt one of three approaches; polling (typically ajax within a setInterval fn), long-polling (eg [COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))), or [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot what is polling? I am more interested with ajax since from the one you said it's the only I currently know

Comment: Polling means making regular ajax requests, say every one or two seconds, to a server-side script that will return the progress statistic you wish to display in the form of a progress bar. The server-side script will typically be separate from the one that initiated the task in question (making a PDF).

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot can you provide a simple example? any server side language will do

Comment: I'm not expert in the server-side aspects of this particular issue. Hopefully someone else will be able to respond.

Comment: Just re-read the question - you say the "during file conversion I am only able to show the status (in numbers (provided by the API I am using))", so how do you do that? - post the client-side code and I'll tell you how to make a progress bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Struts2 take a look at [`Execute and Wait Interceptor`](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html). It creates new thread with your task which will be executed in the background while you can show some progress to the user.

In `struts.xml` file add `execAndWait` interceptor to your long running action and define two results `wait` and `success`.

```
<action name="longRunningAction" class="...">
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
  <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait"/>
  <result name="wait">longRunningAction-wait.jsp</result>
  <result name="success">longRunningAction-success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

You still need to poll this action in your JSP via AJAX or simple page refresh.

Comment: is "defaultStack" really needed?

Comment: Hmm.. YES. Why do you ask?

Comment: You will lose all others interceptors which are defined in `defaultStack`.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying: `During file conversion I am only able to show the status(in numbers(provided by the API I am using))`

What is this number? Is percentage of how much of a file is converted? If it is, then you only need to import `jQuery UI` library and add `.progressbar()`

Comment: it's not in percentage it's ranges from 1 to 1000, 1000 is value for complete

Comment: But it does increase exponentially or is it a random number presenting some stage of conversion?

Comment: it increase exponentially not a random number

Comment: Then I'm guessing you can divide the number by 10, to get required percentage (from 1 to 100), and providing this number to progressbar.

Comment: after that what should I do?

Comment: IF you don't mind using `jQuery UI`, look at this page: http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution:
Use Struts2-Jquery tag

And define indicator on your submit tag with a gif image

eg.

```
 `<form action="...">
     <s:file ..../>
     <sj:submit indicator="imgId"> 
 </form>

 <img id="imgId" src="images/indicator.gif" alt="Loading..."     
  style="display:none"/>
     `
```